# Wrong position after center object using fabric js canvas

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an image on a canvas using FabricJS, after I load the image I call canvas.centerObject(img). I have the same image scaled 2X, I am trying to imaplement a Magnify Glass functionality, everything works fine without centering the image, but as soon as I call canvas.centerObject(img) the bigger image doesn't show in the rigth position.

```
    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function (img) {
        img1 = img;
    img.set({
        width: originalWidth,
        height: originalHeight,
        evented: true,
        selectable: false
    });

    lens = fabric.util.object.clone(img);
    lens.set({
        width: scale * originalWidth,
        height: scale * originalHeight,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {
            ctx.arc(-this.left + x - this.width / 2, -this.top + y - this.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        }
    });

    canvas.add(img, lens);
    canvas.centerObject(img);//*******issue here****
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
    x = e.e.layerX;
    y = e.e.layerY;
    lens.set('left', -(scale - 1) * x);
    lens.set('top', -(scale - 1) * y);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

[Please check on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arnel_1988/u3oL0z7n/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-aligned the bigger image so it shows correctly when you call `canvas.centerObject(img)` .  However, you might like to rethink your design a little to perhaps incorporate object scaling, `scale()` - depending on your implementation needs, of course.

Here's an updated JSFiddle and the tweaked code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/rfdxff5h/

```
  fabric.Image.fromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg', function(img) {
    img1 = img;
    img.set({
      width: originalWidth,
      height: originalHeight,
      evented: true,
      selectable: false
    });

    lens = fabric.util.object.clone(img);
    lens.set({
      top: -225,
      left: 150,
      width: scale * originalWidth,
      height: scale * originalHeight,
      clipTo: function(ctx) {
        ctx.arc(-this.left + x - this.width / 2, -this.top + y - this.height / 2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      }
    });

    canvas.add(img, lens);
    canvas.centerObject(img);//******* issue no longer here****
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
    x = e.e.layerX;
    y = e.e.layerY;
    if (x > 150 && x < 750) {
      lens.set('left', -(scale - 1) * x + 300);
      lens.set('top', -(scale - 1) * y);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: If I understand, the solution is based on this line of code: lens.set('left', -(scale - 1) * x + 300). So basically I have to add 300 to the big image's left to achieve the centerObject from the small image. How can I dynamically calculate that value (300) to make it work for any size of image??

Comment: Half the width of whatever image... but a quarter of the image size needs to be used for the left property of the lens... but that depends on your canvas size also.

Comment: @Arnel Did this answer your question?  Do you mind marking as the answer?  Let me know if you have any other questions as you implement.  Happy to help further.